# Is $[\star]$ a limit point of the sequence $\langle [\frac{1}{1}] , [\frac{1}{2}], [\frac{1}{3}], \dots \rangle$?

Tags: general-topology, equivalence-relations, quotient-spaces

Recall also that in general

> If $X$ is a topological space and $X / \sim$ is a quotient space of $X$, then $U$ is open in $X / \sim \iff \displaystyle\bigcup_{[x] \in U} [x]$ is open in $X$

The question is this: Is $[\star]$ a limit point of the sequence $\big\langle [\frac{1}{n}] \big\rangle_{n=1}^\infty$ in $\mathbb{R} / \sim \hspace{0.2cm}$? To show this, we need to show that for every open nbhd $U$ of $[\star]$, there is $M \in \mathbb{N}$ so that when $n \geq M, [\frac{1}{n}] \in U$.

First, note that $U \neq \{[\star]\}$, i.e. $U$ cannot be a singleton since $[\star] = \mathbb{R} \setminus \mathbb{Q}$ is not open in $\mathbb{R}$. Moreover, $U$ also cannot contain a finite number of $[\frac{1}{n}]$ classes because the union of that finite collection of classes would be neither open nor closed in $\mathbb{R}$. Hence, $U$ must be the entire quotient space with a finite number of  $[\frac{1}{n}]$ classes taken away; we would write this as $U = (\mathbb{R} / \sim) \setminus \{[\frac{1}{n_1}], [\frac{1}{n_2}], [\frac{1}{n_3}], \dots, [\frac{1}{n_k}]\}$. In $\mathbb{R}$, the union of $U$ would take on the appearance of the real line with infinitely many holes taken out of it, the holes of which are at least a finite distance apart from each other, which could be expressed as the union of disjoint, open intervals.

Comment: $[0]$ does not contain any irrationals, as you describe the relation. $[0]$ consists of all integers according to your definition

Comment: @FShrike I apologize for the misunderstanding. The phrase "$[0]$" denotes the class of irrationals because in Thomae's function, if $x$ is irrational, $t(x) = 0$, similar to how $\frac{m}{n} \mapsto \frac{1}{n}$ via $t$; hence $\frac{m}{n} \in [\frac{1}{n}]$. I think the issue here is more of a notation problem. Note that $0 \in [\frac{1}{1}]$ but $[0] = \mathbb{R} \setminus \mathbb{Q}$

Comment: Without fail, $[x]$ refers to the unique equivalence class containing $x$. I recommend you use a different notation, such as $[\pi]$, or $\star$, to refer to the class of irrationals

Comment: @FShrike I have changed $[0]$ to $[\star]$

Comment: @BenjiAltman Yes, well, $\Bbb R/\sim$ itself. That doesn't necessarily imply $\star$ is a limit point of the given sequence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The complement of $U$ is not necessarily finite. For a counterexample,

$$ U = (\mathbb{R} / \sim) \setminus \bigcup_{n=1}^\infty \left[\frac{1}{n!}\right] $$

The only integers relatively prime to $n!$ are of the form $m(n!) \pm 1$, so the union of elements of $U$ is $\mathbb{R} \setminus V$ where

$$ V = \left\{ m \pm \frac{1}{n!} \mid m \in \mathbb{Z}, n \in \mathbb{N} \right\} $$

$V$ is closed in $\mathbb{R}$, and its limit points are the integers. So $U$ is open in $\mathbb{R} \setminus \sim$.

However, the definition of "a limit point" of a sequence $(a_n)$ doesn't require $a_n \in U$ for all $n \geq M$. That's the definition of "converges to a limit". This example $U$ shows that the sequence $\left(\left[\frac{1}{n}\right]\right)_{n=1}^\infty$ does not converge to $[\star]$. But we call $b$ a limit point of $(a_n)$ if **at least one** $a_n$ is in every open neighborhood of $b$. Since every non-empty open set in $\mathbb{R}$ contains a rational number, every open set in $\mathbb{R} / \sim$ containing $[\star]$ also contains some $\left[\frac{1}{n}\right]$, so $[\star]$ is a limit point of $\left(\left[\frac{1}{n}\right]\right)_{n=1}^\infty$.